# What is the proper way to modify a state in a function?

Tags: swiftui

```
@State var test:Bool = false

var body: some View {
  Button() {
   doSomething(test)
  }
}

func doSomething(input:Bool) {
    input = true 
}
```

This gives a compile error

> Cannot assign to value: 'input' is a 'let' constant.

I found one way is to mark the param as input. Is this the best way to edit a state?

Comment: Your state variable is named the same as your parameter. The compiler is complaining about the parameter being a constant. Easiest solution is to name your parameter something other than test. No, your parameter should not be inout — that would just modify the parameter and not the state variable.

Comment: I just tried it, same error. Editing the question.

Comment: You're doing the same thing -- you're trying to set the parameter. It should be `test = input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this:

### Use `Binding`

```
func doSomething(input: Binding<Bool>) {
    input.wrappedValue.toggle()
}
```

### Use `inout`

```
func doSomething(input: inout Bool) {
    input.toggle()
}
```

In both cases, you would call like this:

```
doSomething(input: $test)
```

Bindings are usually used to pass `@State` vars to another view.  I would probably just use Swift's `inout` functionality here.

---

Here is a complete example to play with:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shown1: Bool = false
    @State var shown2: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                if shown1 {
                    TextView(text: "Hello")
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 100)

            Button("Show Toggle") {
                doSomething(input: $shown1)
            }
            ZStack {
                if shown2 {
                    TextView(text: "World!")
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 100)

            Button("Show Toggle") {
                doSomething2(input: &shown2)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func doSomething(input: Binding<Bool>) {
        input.wrappedValue.toggle()
    }
    
    func doSomething2(input: inout Bool) {
        input.toggle()
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried inout and it seems to break the rendering based on States

Comment: Do you have a simple example? How does the Binding work for you?

Comment: Any feedback on the use of Binding?

Comment: yes it works, but quite clumsy. I've heard others that I'm not supposed to set wrappedValue like that but I'll mark as solved since it works.

Comment: inout does not work btw, I think there's some magic happening with that keyword

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the state variable as an argument to the function. Instead, access it directly from the function body:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var test: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            doSomething()
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        test = true 
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot, the function is setting a dynamic state, depending on whats passed in

Comment: You never stated this in your question, could you please elaborate what do you mean by dynamic state?